# Beginner MySQL form issues

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms

Hey hopefully someone can point me in the right direction.

I'm going around in circles with this form I'm trying to submit to a db.

This is my form code

```
 <form action="submission.php" method="post">
   <ul>
       <li><input type="text" name="tips_title" placeholder="Title"></input></li>
       <li><textarea name="tips_text" placeholder="Text"></textarea></li>
       <li><input type="submit" value="Publish"></input></li>
   </ul>
 </form>
```

This is my submission.php file

```
  <?php

   //Connecting to sql db.

   $connect = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'DB NAME', 'PASSWORD', 'DB USERNAME');

   //Sending form data to sql db.

   mysqli_query($connect,"INSERT INTO tips (tips_title, tips_text) VALUES       ('$_POST[tips_title]', '$_POST[tips_text]')";

   ?>
```

Ive tried following tutorials but i still doesnt work.

I just get a blank page upon submit and no updated records in the DB.

Many thanks

Comment: Please switch to [prepared statements](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html) to prevent [SQL injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection). What is the result of `mysqli_query`? And you should swap the values of `'DB NAME'` and `'DB USERNAME'`.

Comment: Your form has also input closing tags </input>

Comment: In dont get any result, just a blank page, It is now showing there is a syntax error on line 5 although it looks fine to me

Comment: In your PHP Script use print_r($_POST) and see whether you are getting the values are not

Comment: That's not what I meant: check the *return value* of `mysqli_query`. If it's `FALSE`, check `mysqli_error`.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about syntax error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use

```
$connect=mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
```

Which is preferred format

Comment: I changed to this but still no result..

Comment: Try to print the post values using print_r($_POST) and see whether you are getting any data

Comment: Nothing at all, still a blank page

Comment: At least you should get the empty array as array() might be problem with your html code

Comment: I run your script i am getting the data but the problem is you are not closing the statement with ")" 
The query will be 
mysqli_query($connect,"INSERT INTO tips (tips_title, tips_text) VALUES       ('$_POST[tips_title]', '$_POST[tips_text]')");

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
mysqli_query($connect,"INSERT INTO tips (tips_title, tips_text) VALUES     ('".$_POST[tips_title]."', '".$_POST[tips_text]."')";
```

From:

```
mysqli_query($connect,"INSERT INTO tips (tips_title, tips_text) VALUES       ('$_POST[tips_title]', '$_POST[tips_text]')";
```

---

Did you check this parameters?:

```
'localhost', 'DB NAME', 'PASSWORD', 'DB USERNAME'
```

And then you can catch your wrongs with using `try/catch`

Comment: I tried this but still no result, the form just goes to a blank page. stumped i can manually insert data into the form through phpmyadmin

Comment: I've edited yet my answer. Look this.

Answer (score -1):

this is the correct syntax while fetching data using superglobal variable `$_POST['tips_title']` not  `$_POST[tips_title];`

```
 mysqli_query($connect,"INSERT INTO tips (tips_title, tips_text) VALUES('".$_POST['tips_title']."', '".$_POST['tips_text']."')");
```

or a better way:

```
$tips_title=mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['tips_title']);
$tips_text=mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['tips_text']);
    mysqli_query($connect,"INSERT INTO tips (tips_title, tips_text) VALUES('$tips_title', '$tips_text')");
```

Comment: Yes, but this is still vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: @MarcelKorpel you are right but for now i gave him the reason of his error.

Comment: @MarcelKorpel anyways i updated my code.

Comment: Where you are closing the statement with ")"

Comment: @PavanKumar that was a typo anyways thanks for pointing.

Comment: Don't mix `mysqli_*` functions with `mysql_*` functions! There's also `mysqli_real_escape_string` (or use prepared statements).